# Do I need my Canadian passport to travel into Canada from the US

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, paperwork, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen. I have lived in the US and have a permanent resident card. I ordered my Canadian passport but won't receive it before it's time for me to travel. Can I travel into Canada and get my passport at the Winnipeg passport office in person?

Comment: Do you currently reside in the US?  Will you be traveling into Canada from the US?  If so, by land or air?

Comment: do you have any other proof Canadian citizenship?

Comment: I am driving from Utah to Ontario. I have my birth certificate as well as my US permanent resident card.

Comment: I think you might be okay with that. If you can reach a Canada border officer they'll admit you as a Canadian with a birth certificate + ID; having the green card is even better. The usual problem is that this isn't enough to get you on a plane to Canada to reach the border officer that way, but you can drive to the border.

Comment: @KateGregory since green card holders can enter with their green cards only, additional proof of Canadian citizenship should be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. now my only problem is that they refuse to hold my passport at the Winnipeg office and let me pick it up there. they have to courier it to me in Utah. too late for my trip connections unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If travelling by air, the only accepted document other than a passport is a NEXUS card, as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=CA&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=CA&selDest=Canada&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines

Otherwise, as stated by the [CBSA](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html), you can also use a citizenship certificate, **or** Green card (not mentioned), **or** enhanced driving licence.

Or, alternatively, a birth certificate **plus** one of the following

• CANPASS card

• Commercial Driver Registration Program card

• Ordinary driving license

• Employment or student card with photo and signature

• Provincial Health Insurance Card

• Provincial identity card

• Canadian Forces Identification

• Police Identification

• Firearms Acquisition Certificate

• Social Insurance Number Card

• Credit Card

• Vehicle Insurance Certificate

• Vehicle Registration

Comment: I am a permanent resident of the US. I only have my birth certificate from Canada. My drivers license and concealed carry permit and all other identification are from Utah, not Canada. I have applied for my Canadian passport and would like to pick it up in person in Winnipeg. Can I cross the border and go into Winnipeg to get it without my passport.

Comment: @GmaB As Long as you have photo ID matching your birth certificate, it will suffice in practice (after all, a Canadian cannot be refused entry to their own Country). So Show your Utah DL and you should be fine, possibly with some delays

Comment: @GmaB, show the green card too (or instead). A green card alone is [sufficient to visit Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16) even if you aren't Canadian. It also confirms your country of birth.

Comment: Canada admits US permanent residents with only their green card, and so does the US.

Comment: @phoog That too